# Tor's .desktop entry does not work: "Exec" key with reserved characters

Tags: 16.04, launcher, tor

When installing the Tor-Browser, one can create a .desktop entry in ~/.local/share/applications/ in order to be able to open tor using an application's launcher. This is proving problematic on my end. This is the important parameter in the .desktop entry:

```
Exec=sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

Now doing `desktop-file-validate start-tor-browser.desktop`, I get the following errors:

```
start-tor-browser.desktop: hint: value item "Security" in key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" can be extended with another category among the following categories: Settings, or System
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '|' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '|' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '(' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a non-escaped character '$' in a quote, but it should be escaped with two backslashes ("\\$")
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '$' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '*' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ')' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
```

Even after escaping the """ characters with "\"", so it becomes:

```
Exec=sh -c '\\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" --detach || ([ !  -x \\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" ] && \\"$(dirname \\"$*\\")\\"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
```

I still get errors:

```
start-tor-browser.desktop: hint: value item "Security" in key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" can be extended with another category among the following categories: Settings, or System
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '\\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" --detach || ([ !  -x \\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" ] && \\"$(dirname \\"$*\\")\\"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '\\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" --detach || ([ !  -x \\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" ] && \\"$(dirname \\"$*\\")\\"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ')' outside of a quote
start-tor-browser.desktop: error: value "sh -c '\\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" --detach || ([ !  -x \\"/opt/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser\\" ] && \\"$(dirname \\"$*\\")\\"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character ''' outside of a quote
```

Comment: @karel, you don't believe in Tor's methodology then. I did what is suggested here: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux. I passed the flag --register-app to have the .desktop entry.

Comment: I'm using Tor Browser right now in 18.04. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igCuS.png

Comment: @karel, we're talking about ubuntu 16.04. Not 18.04. As you should be aware, package versions are different in different ubuntu versions.

Comment: I used the same Tor app in 16.04 that I'm using in 18.04. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igCuS.png

Comment: Link to my solution: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/cant-verify-tor-package/16598#16598

Comment: @karel, I had already tried your solution (it's mentioned in torbrowser's-launcher repo) but it does not work. The browser does not install and gives several errors.

Comment: @karel, https://imgur.com/a/fgAyGMk